# sed commmad in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, operating-system

The command I am using is this:

```
sed 's/\ (/\(/g' file2
```

The text I am getting as its output is this:

```
swissadme\(9).csv
```

The output I want in this is:

```
swissadme\ (9).csv
```

I want space between the two "\" that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments for `s` are `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`, but you seem to have them reversed. What you want to replace comes first, the result comes second.

Also, backslash is special for sed and needs to be doubled to match or output literally. So, the working command is

```
sed 's/\\(/\\ (/g'
```